# My ios app has been rejected due to crash but its working on my device

Tags: ios, app-store

My app has been rejected on apple store, but its working on my iphone and Ipad (emulator)

this is rejection message :

> Your app crashed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 11.3.1 connected to an
>   IPv6 network when we tapped SIGN IN button after entering credentials.
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

This is logs attached by apple

http://digdyn.biz/logs.rar

In fact I don't have IPV6 network.

Comment: Have you tired running your app in `release` mode on the emulator and see if crash happens?

Comment: you need to symbolicate the crash logs and see what happened

Comment: Crash log is not understandable and I asked my question to help analyzing this crash log. @Paulw11

Comment: No-one else can help you because we don't have your code.  Use this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: @Paulw11 I will research how to understand the log files, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @MRFrhn Its working fine on release mode !